# tkinter unbind function do not work as I want

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I have some code here:

```
def __GameOver__(self):

    self.canvas.unbind('<Up>');

    #other function ---

    time.sleep(2)

    self.canvas.bind('<Up>', func);

    self.root.after(40,self.GameMainLoop)
    pass
```

What I want is that when the game is over , the player can't do anything until the 'other functions' and time.sleep(2) run over. However , while I'm testing , I find that if I keep pressing the button **after the** **canvas.unbind('< Up >');** **but before**  **canvas.bind('< Up >');**.The message still can be received after **canvas.bind('< Up >');**.This is not what I want. But I can not find other ways. Is there some wrong about the understanding about the function unbind?  Or is there something like 'event sequence' that I should clear before the bind function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is not with the unbinding, it's with `sleep`. When you call sleep, no events can be processed, so the processing of the events is done after the sleep is over, and when your `<Up>` button is bound again. Consider unbinding, then using the `after` method to do the sleeping, and then call a function that binds the key again.

This is an example. It changes the label when you press up and sleeps when you press the button. During this sleep the up key does nothing.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text='Bla')
        self.label.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text='Button', command=self.sleep)
        self.button.pack()

        self.root.bind('<Up>', self.func)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def func(self, event):
        self.label.config(text='Up '+str(random.random()))

    def sleep(self):
        self.root.unbind('<Up>')
        self.label.config(text='sleeping')
        self.root.after(2000, self.done_sleeping)

    def done_sleeping(self):
        self.label.config(text='done sleeping')
        self.root.bind('<Up>', self.func)

App()
```